# Write lines to file in expl3

Tags: expl3, external-files, programming

Common programming languages (PL), e.g. `Python` allow append lines to opened file like `file_object = open('sample.txt', 'a')`.

How it is possible to do in expl3 PL? My MWE adds only last argument of `\somemacro`. Please point to the right place in [Interface3](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) how to do it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\iow_new:N \l_totoc_iow

\NewDocumentCommand{\somemacro}{ m }
{
    \iow_open:Nn \l_totoc_iow {\g_file_curr_name_str.dat}
    \iow_now:Nn \l_totoc_iow { #1 }
    \iow_close:N \l_totoc_iow
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\somemacro{tofile}
\somemacro{tofile2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: remember that (la)tex is **not** a common programming language. I'm actually not even sure if (la)tex supports appending to a file. Normally the file would be open for the entire compilation

Comment: The variable should be named like `\l_pkgname_totoc_iow` (note the suffix).

Comment: As soon as you open a file for writing, its previous content is destroyed. Just remove `\iow_close:N \l_totoc_iow`

Comment: That's the reason why LaTeX2e keeps open the `.aux` file and writes all other write instructions into it (and keeping many files open is unpracticable if you only can open a dozen or so)

Comment: There are ways to do this with lualatex though.

Comment: Remark: I know that there's no existing expl3 answer there; nevertheless • the principle is the same (read all, rewrite) and • if anyone wants to post an expl3 answer, please **post the answer there**. That way people who find that question can find your answer more easily.

Answer (score 4):

The rule of TeX is that when a file is opened for writing in it, its previous content is destroyed. There's nothing to do about it.

Guessing from your naming of the file handle, you want to do something similar to producing a table of contents.

How is this solved by LaTeX? Instructions to write to the toc file are *not* directly written in it, because it cannot be known when it will be used for reading and printing from it. Rather, the instructions are written in the `.aux` file and a new version of the `.toc` file is written out at end document, when nothing more will be printed (LaTeX has already scanned `\end{document}`). Thus at each time during the LaTeX run, the *previous* version of the `.toc` file is available for reading.

Note that you cannot have a file opened for writing and read from it.